# I can't store response comes from payment api

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

ı have been devoloing an e-commerce system but ı have problem with iyzipay payment api. I make successful request and get response from server but I can't store data comes from server. anyone help?

```
 let returnedData = {}

  iyzipay.payment.create(paymentRequest, function (err, result) {
    if (err) {
      return next(new CustomError("Ödeme başarısız.", 500))
    } 
     return returnedData = result
  })

  //ı can't see data here and return empty {}
  console.log(returnedData)

  // but ı can see here when ı wait 1 second
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(returnedData)
  }, 1000);
```

Comment: Do you know what callbacks, stack and queue are?

Comment: I have little knowledge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're calling an `async` function you should `await` for it's result. That's why your first console log doesn't print the result and ater 1 sec does, because in that time(+ the execution time for the stack) you're getting the result

The function that can be `await`ed:

```js
function createPayment(paymentRequest) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        iyzipay.payment.create(paymentRequest, function (err, result) {
            if (err) reject(new CustomError("Ödeme başarısız.", 500));
            resolve(result);
        });
    });
}
```

Generally:

```js
(async () => {
    const request = {/* whatever */};
    try {
        const res = await createPayment(request);
        console.log(res); // Now it's here
    } catch(e) { console.error(e); }
})();
```

You're probably in a route so the actual code would be:

```js
app.use('/payment', async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const result = await createPayment(req);
        console.log(result); // Now it's here
        res.end();
    } catch(e) { next(e); }
})
```

Comment: thanks my brother ı figured out thanks to you, thanks agaainn :))

Answer (score 0):

Your first console is getting called before the request gets complete. When waited for 1 sec request is completed and response is stored in the returnData variable.
So for your requirement try using promise or call a function to store the response from the create payment function itself with the response as a parameter.

Comment: I tried but ı can't get data eihter way. can you share example snippet?